# Linux shell script to iteratively call same Python program with different parameters

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7

I have a Python program that requires different parameters each time. The parameters are URLs stored in a file called `urls.txt`. So for example if `urls.txt` contains:

```
abc.com
xyz.com
def.com
mno.com
```

I'd want to execute:

```
python myProgram.py -u 'abc.com' -f output.txt
python myProgram.py -u 'xyz.com' -f output.txt
python myProgram.py -u 'def.com' -f output.txt
python myProgram.py -u 'mno.com' -f output.txt
```

How is this done?

Comment: This question is not "too broad" at all. There are only a few, short, answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for url in `cat urls.txt`
do
    python myProgram.py -u "$url" -f output.txt
done
```

It can also be done with a while loop and `read`:

```
while read url
do
    python myProgram.py -u "$url" -f output.txt
done <urls.txt
```

Comment: I smell a useless use of cat ;-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/748858

Comment: The `cat` method has the advantage of not dropping the last line of the file if is is not terminated by newline. This can also be handled with the less readable version of while...read, `while read url || [[ -n $url ]]; do python myProgram.py -u "$url" -f output.txt; done` . Seems that the cat is not so useless :)

Comment: Or even `xargs -n1 -Ifoo python myProgram.py -u "foo" -f output.txt < urls.txt`...